# PS::Simplification with 3d points

Tags: cgal, polyline, terrain, simplification

Im trying to simplify 3d polylines using CGAL::Simplify, is a terrain so the elevation does not matter for the simplification but I need to carry them because I need them on simplified polylines. The polylines can be open or closed (polygon).
The problem occurs when I try to call PS::simplify with 3d points. I checked and it work ok with 2d points. The funny is that it accept 3d points for parameters begin and end of the polyline but do not accept for the back_inserter parameter.
Is there any version of simplify that work completely with 3d points or I´m missing something?

on the code:

```
  PS::simplify(P1.begin(), P1.end(), CostSquare(), Stop(0.5), std::back_inserter(Result),Closed);
```

Templates and parametes definitions:

```
 namespace PS = CGAL::Polyline_simplification_2;
 typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Epic;
 typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<Epic>  K;
 typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K> Polygon_2;
 Polygon_2_2 P1;
 std::deque<Point_2> Result;
 typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;
```

Thank you

Carlos A. Rabelo

Comment: We give an [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyline_simplification_2/Polyline_simplification_2_2simplify_terrain_8cpp-example.html) for a terrain so I would be glad if you could put a complete self contained cpp on gist.github.com.   In the above code snippet I am wondering what `Point_2` is in your program.

Comment: With ct as the first parameter of PS::Simplification is not working on my aplication because of the bug #5439 already posted on git (Mr. Irineu is taking care of it) . I´m trying to work around this error so I´m trying to simplify the terrain contour lines one by one using this different version of PS::Simplification and I´m facing this problem. Observe that I´m calling a different version of PS::Simplify wich parameters 1 an 2 are the begin and the end of the polyline (not a ct).  result is : std::deque<Point_2> Result;

Comment: Sorry I forgot, point 2 is : typedef K::Point_2 Point_2;